# Extraneous Checkboxes? Not sure where they came from

Tags: php, forms

Here is the code.

```
<?php
$dirname = 'music';

$dir = new DirectoryIterator($dirname);

foreach ($dir as $path => $splFileInfo)
{
if ($splFileInfo->isDir())
    continue;


 $output = explode(' ', $splFileInfo, 5);
echo "<form>";
?><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $output[0] ?>" /><?php echo "$output[0]"; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $output[1] ?>" /><?php echo "$output[1]"; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $output[2] ?>" /><?php echo "$output[2]"; ?>
<?php echo "</form>";

}
?>
```

This causes there to be two extra checkboxes after the ones coded for. Example: [image since it won't let me post images yet.](http://www.braindeaddesigns.com/cms/Content.png)

Comment: Saw nothing strange there, nothing that you haven't told the script to do.

Comment: Have you got this set to ignore the directories "." and ".."?

Comment: Seems like your loop echos 3 checkboxes in a separate form each time (and that keys `1` and `2` are not set in that array). So, why is that not expected behavior?

Comment: Tabs are your friend.  Left aligned text is **wrong** in any mainstream language.

Comment: @rockerest It is tabbed in my editor. The formatting changed when I posted it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something in the loop that should be done outside it.  I expected that exact output based on the code, so let me take a stab at a fix here:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$dirname = 'music';
$dir     = new DirectoryIterator($dirname);
foreach ($dir as $path => $splFileInfo)
{
    if ($splFileInfo->isFile())
    {
        $filename = $splFileInfo->getFilename();
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?= $filename; ?>" /><label><?= $filename; ?></label><br />
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</form>
```